# Lenovo Yoga 510 14ISK (type 80S7) touchpad doesn't recognize clics

Tags: drivers, touchpad, lenovo-laptop, synaptics-touchpad

I migrated to Linux and came back to Win10. Always worked the touchpad until the last Win10 installation, but now it doesn't recognize the double click and the physical ones. However, the triple-click works but I only can set it as a launcher of Cortana because of the awful Synaptics software.

When I was within Linux I reinstalled the kernel to customize it.

I reinstalled Win10, official drivers, drivers by Win updates, updated the bios, unplug and plug the battery, configured the Synaptics software...

Any idea?

Comment: What make is your touchpad (Elan, Synaptics) and what is its driver?

Comment: According to the Lenovo web, this is the driver: Synaptics 19.4.18.20, Elan 11.4.108.3

Comment: Try to find from the Device Manager which one is it among these two.

Comment: It is not listed in Device Manager. No mouse appear. I see Synaptics SMBus Driver inside System Devices.

Comment: (1) Could you add a screenshot from regedit of the contents of `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Synaptics\SynTP\TouchPadPS2`? (2) [Disable SmartSense](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-fix-this-Lenovo-laptop-touchpad-problem-after-each-use-of-the-keyboard-even-if-only-one-key-is-pressed-the-first-tap-of-the-touchpad-does-not-work), (3) In Device Manage, right-click the Synaptics device and delete it *with its driver* and reboot for Windows to install its own driver.

Comment: (1) There is no Synaptics folder (2) There is no mouse settings neither anything similar when right click on the pc device (I right-click with touchable screen) (3) I'm going to try it now

Comment: I've just tried, nothing happened

Comment: Pretty weird, it doesn't even seem like the Synaptics software is installed at all. Check all the other drivers and BIOS versions for your model. I think that on the Ideapad the F6 key controls the touchpad, so try hitting it once.

Comment: I had checked that before 

Comment: Last idea : Check the Event Viewer for errors.

Comment: Maybe it's a hardware failure. Boot a Linux Live CD (e.g. Ubuntu) and see if it works there. If it works there, it's only a driver problem. If it doesn't work there too, it's likely a hardware failure.

Comment: It worked on Linux, but I will try again later, maybe I broke it when I discharged battery.